# SharePoint XSLT $AllRows Iteration Behaving Unexpectedly On Live SharePoint Site

Tags: xml, sharepoint, web-parts, xslt

I'm new to XSLT, and I'm also new to Sharepoint.

I've modified my XLV Web Part so that it has the following xml:

```
<xsl>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"> 
  <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/> 
  <xsl:param name="AllRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[$EntityName = '' or (position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow)]"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="View[@BaseViewID='0']" mode="full" ddwrt:ghost="always">        
   <div class="box whatsnew">
    <div class="boxcontent">
     <h2><xsl:value-of select="List/@title" /></h2>
     <p><xsl:value-of select="List/@description" /></p>

     <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$AllRows">      
       <li>
        <em><xsl:value-of select="@Date" /></em><br />
        <a href="{@Link}"><xsl:value-of select="@Text" /></a>
       </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl>
```

When I view my WebPart in Design mode in SharePoint designer, the list items are populated as I would expect.

But when I publish my changes to the SharePoint site, three of the values are returned as blank. These values are the values inside of the for-each statement: @Date, @Text, and @Link.

I've searched for answers. To no avail. Any ideas as to why this code doesn't work on my live Sharepoint site? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the input XML and the output? Then we won't have to ask whether you are getting `<h2>` elements, and an `<li>` for each input row, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

their is a problem with your declaration of AllRows variable. it seems its getting either epmpty rows.

Kindly check the conditional part of filter statement which looks like the problamitic area. i would recommend first remove the conditional part and check if the data is completely retrieved.  and then modify your filter statement

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was SPD bug, when changes in code was not applied to page, but was displayed in SPD. Next actions have solved this problem: Just enter something directly in a column of the list view in SharePoint Designer (In Design Mode) and save the changes. After that, remove the string you entered first and save the page again. Then the ghost page should work also in browser.
[Link to thread where i found this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9c679a98-a530-43fa-9559-989910681ecc/sharepoint-designer-does-not-save-changes-to-view-xslt?prof=required)